# Problem with saving/editing record

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've created a custom Visualforce landing page for my account tab and now when i want to make some edits i am not able to click on the fields like they are not editable. Also when I try to save the record, it doesn't want to get saved.

Here is how my code looks like.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" showHeader="true" wizard="false" readOnly="false" rendered="true" showChat="true" standardStylesheets="false"
      tabStyle="account"  >
   <style>
      .activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white; width: 170px; height: 20px; padding-top: 6px; font-size: 12px; font-style: bold; border-top: none;
         background-image:none;}
      .inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black; width: 170px; height: 20px; padding-top: 6px; font-size: 12px; font-style: bold; border: none;
         background-image: none}
   </style>

<apex:pageBlock id="block1" >
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="section2" columns="2" collapsible="true" title="Important Information!">
        <apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Publisher_Username__c}"/>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Contacted_by__c}"/>
        <apex:outputfield value="{!Account.Publisher_ID__c}"/>


    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <script>
        twistSection(document.getElementById('{!$Component.block1.section1}').getElementsByTagName('img')[0])
    </script>

</apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="tabdetails" 
                  id="AccountTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" 
                  inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab"  >   
      <apex:tab label="Details" name="AccDetails" id="tabdetails" style="background-color: white;">
         <apex:detail relatedList="false" title="true" inlineEdit="true"/>
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Contacts" name="Contacts" id="tabContact" >
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="contacts"  />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Opportunities" name="Opportunities" 
                id="tabOpp">
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" 
                           list="opportunities" />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Open Activities" name="OpenActivities" 
                id="tabOpenAct">
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" 
                           list="OpenActivities" />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Activity History" name="ActivityHistory" id="tabActHist">
          <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" list="ActivityHistories" />
      </apex:tab>
      <apex:tab label="Notes & Attachments" 
                name="NotesAndAttachments" id="tabNoteAtt" >
         <apex:relatedList subject="{!account}" 
                           list="CombinedAttachments" />
      </apex:tab>
   </apex:tabPanel>

</apex:page>
```

Please advise,

Darko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to my problem. Since I disabled standardStylesheets="false". The code confuses with the existing code and because of that i am not able to save my record or view initial date as a calendar field.

So to fix this, problem i need the style sheet to be set to true.

```
standardStylesheets="true"
```

Problem solved.

Cheers,

Darko

Answer (score 1):

Did you try  `apex:inlineEditSupport` ? If not, you may try something like this:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Account.Name}" >
<apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="svbtn" /> 
</apex:outputField>
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}"  id="svbtn"/>
```

Comment: thank you for your input but inline edit support works only for forms. In my code i tried everything but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: In order to save the record to the database, you have to use form tag if I am not wrong.